# Getting all serial numbers related to an assembly to display

Tags: reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

First time asking a question here in SO. I am working with Report Builder, and I am having issues with getting all serial numbers for a particular assembly number in a manufacturing setting.  Sometimes there is only a single serial number per assembly, sometimes there are multiple serial numbers in an assembly.

Admittedly, I'm not the most versed with report builder.

Here is the expression that I have created to try and solve the issue:

```
=Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(1, 1, Fields!SerialNumber.Value,"JobHead")),", ")
```

with this code, I am able to get all the serial numbers for the Assemblies to display, but now they show on every page instead of listing the serial number for the specific assembly:

Example Image:

[image]

Showing that two assemblies are selected, 0 and 2:

[image]

Page for assembly 0 shows serial numbers for both assembly 0 and 2:

[image]

For this example, I have selected two Assemblies, numbers 0 and 2, you will notice two serial numbers listed for "ASM 0" (assembly 0).  The true result should only display serial number "0003" whereas the "0001" should only display on the report page for Assembly 2.

I need help populating the correct serial number/s on their respected assembly reports.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
=iif(CountDistinct(fields!SerialNumber.Value)>1,Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(1, 1, Fields!SerialNumber.Value,"JobHead")),", "),fields!SerialNumber.value)
```

Credit to: Milkah Gichaba